# How to connect to a security camera in linux

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a YI home security camera that I want to connect to my linux pc. Is there software that I could install?

Comment: It looks like Yi recommends the mobile app, but they also have software for windows and mac. I'm not seeing a linux alternative, so your best bet is probably getting the windows software and trying to get it running with wine https://www.yitechnology.com/yi-home-pc-app

Comment: I would imagine that the connection might work without a special software, if standard protocols are used from Wifi to image stream transmission

Answer (score 0):

can run the Windows version in Wine from [kami](https://www.kamihome.com/firmware/) don't download from Yi site it will not work